# Encog regularization for C# samples/usage

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I wonder did Encog developers implemented regularization for backpropogation algorithm? I seen RegularizationStrategy class for java, but didn't find something similar for C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 3.2 it was not implemented for .NET (that was one of the reasons why I quit using Encog). I don't know about 3.3 for sure, but it seems that things are still the same. Java RegularizationStrategy seems to be community contribution (see https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/issues/28). If you absolutely want Encog, you can translate java code into C# version yourself, it should not be very difficult. But it looks like even java class only implements L1 regularization.